# best way to pass a variable between two php pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Need to pass a variable from `index.php` to `edit.php`.

The variable should be unvisible for visitors, so address bar is not allowed.

First way - using a form on `index.php` with `action` attribute - `edit.php`.

Problem with using a form is a warning about re-submitting which appears each time `edit.php` is refreshed.

Second way - using ajax call on `index.js` to change a session variable on php side.

Downside of using ajax is an extra path - firstly go to `server side` (to change php) - then to `client side` (success function to get the new value) - and again to server side (go to `edit.php` using the new variable).

What is the right way?

Is there a simple way like this:

`location.href = 'edit.php', set x = 5`

And on `edit.php` to get this:

`echo $x` (result 5);

Comment: Third way - session.

Comment: `location.href = 'edit.php?x=5'`? then of course the page has to read the current "search" property of the current URL and deal with x=5

Comment: @u_mulder, you probably mean `second way` from my post?

Comment: @JaromandaX, address bar is not allowed, read the post again, pls

Comment: indeed ... I just read `location.href = 'edit.php', set x = 5` and thought OP was clueless

Comment: Where do you need the variable in `edit.php`, in the PHP itself or just in the front-end?

Comment: Post, Get, Ajax, Session, Cookie is everything visible in console, so if u want unvisible for visitors then encrypt and send

Comment: @Phil, I need the variable on php side

Comment: Can you please define **exactly** what _"the variable should be unvisible for visitors"_ means?

Comment: @Phil, not visible means - not visible in `address bar`

Comment: And what about in the user's browser console, network console or local cookies? Exactly how hidden from the user should this variable be?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom cookie in `index.js` and append to `document.cookie` and when a request to `edit.php` is made, it will be available.

index.js

```
const custom_cookie = "x=5";
document.cookie = custom_cookie;
.....
window.location = 'edit.php';
```

edit.php

```
$cookie_name = 'x';
echo $_COOKIE[$cookie_name]
```

Comment: But cookies are visible for users. That is a requrement from OP (to not be visible).

Comment: @Andreas I get the feeling OP means not visible in the UI (ie address bar)

Comment: You don't prefix the existing cookie value when setting new ones. It's weird like that. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie#Write_a_new_cookie

Comment: Ohh, my bad. Updating it.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use PHP Sessions.

```
//index.php
$_SESSION['varname'] = $var_value;

//edit.php
$var_value = $_SESSION['varname'];
```

Remember to run the `session_start()`; statement on both these pages before you try to access the  $_SESSION array, and also before any output is sent to the browser.

Comment: on start I'm not on the server side, but on client side

Comment: You said your files are index.php and edit.php then your in the server side bro

Comment: of course not, `index.php` loaded on a local comp is a client side.

Comment: how do you run the index.php file? do you have any Xampp or Wamp..?

Comment: @KhalilDaNish OP is saying that the `x` value comes from the client-side so it is not known when PHP parses `index.php`. It is only known in the browser after the page is rendered

Answer (score 0):

If the parameter must remain invisible in the UI (ie, not in the address bar) and you need to avoid POST requests due to page reloading, you can achieve this with two requests...

Either one AJAX POST then a GET, ie

```js
fetch('set-session-var.php', {
  method: 'post',
  body: 'x=5',
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  }
}).then(res => {
  if (res.ok) {
    window.location = 'edit.php'
  }
})
```

or use a [Post / Redirect / Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern, eg

```html
<form action="set-session-var.php" method="post">
  <!-- set the "x" value however and whenever you want -->
  <button type="submit" name="x" value="5">Go</button>
</form>
```

```php
// set-session-var.php
session_start();
$_SESSION['x'] = $_POST['x'];
header('Location: edit.php'); // omit this if using the AJAX version
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Cookie...

index.php:

```
setcookie("x", 5);
```

edit.php:

```
echo $_COOKIE["x"];
```

Comment: OP says in another comment... _"on start I'm not on the server side, but on client side"_ so they cannot use PHP's `setcookie()`